# Dividing Larger Array into Smaller Array

Tags: java

I'm working on a project and currently I have an array setup like the following:

```
private int[] rowHeights;
this.rowHeights = new int[] {3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4};
```

This rowHeights array can be larger or smaller, depending on what values are initialised in the code. What needs to happen is that I have a second array setup like so:

```
private int[] rowHeightsTwo = new int[7];
```

With this, I need to take the values from rowHeights and put them into rowHeights two in a formation like so: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.

So basically, rowHeightsTwo needs to hold all of the values. So you loop through the original rowHeights array and move it into the rowHeightsTwo but when you reach the largest index of rowHeightsTwo you need to reverse the counter and add to the existing rowHeightsTwo array.

To put it in a better perspective:

```
rowHeightsTwo[0] = 3
rowHeightsTwo[1] = 1
rowHeightsTwo[2] = 2
rowHeightsTwo[3] = 4
rowHeightsTwo[4] = 6
rowHeightsTwo[5] = 8
rowHeightsTwo[6] = 13 (because 9+3 from the previous array)
rowHeightsTwo[7] = 4 (because 1+3 from the last two values of rowHeights)
```

I've got it working for the first eight values (3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1) but being a Java newbie I have no idea how to reverse the counter in the For Loop to add to the existing indexes.

I'm using this For Loop for the heights currently:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.rowHeights.length; k++)
    {
        this.rowHeightsTwo[i] = this.rowHeights[i]
    }
```

So my issue is to figure out how to reverse the counter so I can add together additional values to rowHeightsTwo. My assumption would be a conditional that would run when i tries to go greater than 7 and set the counter to reverse (i++) but I would probably need a second counter to keep looping through the original array.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question is that if the first array has a size bigger then the second array, then you want all the remaining values to be added to the last index of the second array. If thats the case this should work fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        
    if(i < arr2.length) {
            
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
            
    } else {
            
        arr2[arr2.length-1] += arr[i]; 
            
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int[] rowHeights = {3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3};
int[] rowHeightsTwo = new int[8];
for (int i = 0, j = 0, d = 1; i < rowHeights.length; i++, j += d) {
    if (j < 0 || j >= rowHeightsTwo.length)
        j += d = -d;
    rowHeightsTwo[j] += rowHeights[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowHeightsTwo));
```

output

```
[3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 4]
```

`j += d = -d;` is `d = -d;` and then `j += d;`